# How can I use PowerShell to do a .net Regex matches method AND add a timeout?

Tags: regex, powershell

I've been playing with using PowerShell to create a regex object and use the `Regex.Matches()` method... that that all works fine.  But now I've created a TimeSpan object in Powershell (again, easy) and I want to pass that to the `Matches()` method's `matchTimeout` property to restrict how long the .NET engine permits for a match.

Basically I've got all of the syntax down save for applying the timespan to `matchTimeout` property:

```
$maxtime = new-timespan -seconds 1

$regex = new-object regex('hel.', ([System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::MultiLine,[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase))

$matchups = $regex.matches("helo hela helt help")

$matchups.count
```

How do I plug in `$maxtime`?  (And yes, it's a trivial example and there are other ways to do it... I'm just looking for an example of the PowerShell syntax to get a value into `matchTimeout`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the constructor that allows a `matchTimeout` value.

```
PS> [regex]::new

OverloadDefinitions                                                                                                                   
-------------------                                                                                                                   
regex new(string pattern)                                                                                                             
regex new(string pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions options)                                                        
regex new(string pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions options, timespan matchTimeout)

PS> $maxtime = new-timespan -seconds 1
PS> $regex = New-Object -TypeName regex -ArgumentList 'hel.', ([System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::MultiLine,[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase), $maxtime

PS> $regex.MatchTimeout.TotalSeconds
1
```

This does not work in PS2.0 as the matchtimeout was a new feature in .NET 4.5+

Comment: BTW the options may be specified inside the string: `'(?mi)pattern', 'None', $maxtime`

Comment: Excellent!  I saw the constructor in the MSDN docs but didn't know how to put that into New-Object.  Many thanks.  (Isn't there a button somewhere where I can mark this as THE answer, short of upvoting it?)  Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. There's a checkmark right below the arrows

Comment: Oh. Duh.  I was looking for the MSDN "Mark as the answer" or something like that.  <wince/>

Answer (score 1):

The static `Regex.Matches()` method has [an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160201(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a timeout argument as well:

```
$string   = 'helo hela helt help'
$pattern  = 'hel.'
$options  = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]'MultiLine,IgnoreCase'
$maxtime  = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 1

$matchups = [regex]::Matches($string, $pattern, $options, $maxtime)
```

Comment: Mathias, I appreciate the response but it doesn't seem to work -- in other cases I get four matches, and this returns zero every time (and for any size of $maxtime).  I'm cutting and pasting with a $maxtime of 70 seconds... can you assist me?  Thanks.

Comment: Try without the 4th parameter (but then you lose the timeout):  
  
$matchups = [regex]::Matches('hel.', 'helo hela helt help', 'MultiLine,IgnoreCase')  
  
or, if still needed try like this:  
  
`[TimeSpan]$maxtimeout=1  
  
$matchups = [regex]::Matches('hel.', 'helo hela helt help', 'MultiLine,IgnoreCase',  [TimeSpan]$maxtimeout)`

@MarkMinasi

Comment: @holbizmetrics Problem was I accidentally swapped the first two arguments :)